# Windows authentication in VC++

Tags: authentication, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to find a simple solution to authenticate the user in Windows. I'd like to use MFC framework to achieve that.

I googled about this and found that I need to use the following Win32 API function:

`LogonUser(L"LocalServer", L"NT AUTHORITY", NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken)`

But I don't know how to make it work. As per MSDN documentation it returns zero on failure.

Also while searching for this I came across term **Impersonation**. It would be great If someone can explain this.

Can someone point out to a good article or resource for explaining this topic. Also it would be great to see a working example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way to check user security credentials in Windows:

```
BOOL Logon(const CString& sLogin, const CString& sPassword)
{
    HANDLE hToken = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    CString sDomain;
    CString sUser;
    int nPos = sLogin.Find(_T("\\"));
    if (nPos != -1)
    {
        sDomain = sLogin.Mid(0, nPos);
        sUser = sLogin.Mid(nPos + 1, sLogin.GetLength() - nPos - 1);
    }

    if (!sDomain.IsEmpty())
    {
        if(!::LogonUser(sUser, sDomain, sPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken))
            return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!::LogonUser(sLogin, _T("."), sPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken))
            return FALSE;
    }

    if(!::ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken))
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Solution doesn't works, always returns TRUE, even if I enter incorrect username or password.

Comment: That's weird. Are you using Windows domains or not?

Comment: Yes I am using Windows domain.
For sLogin parameter I passed something like _T("domain\\username"). But it always returns TRUE.
When I changed LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS to LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, then it always returns FALSE.

Comment: Works great on my machine. What is your OS?

Comment: changing LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS to LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE worked for me. check this msdn documentation for more detail https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396